# How to Add/Replace/Delete Escape Characters in strings - Python

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8, byte

I have some problems regarding escape characters.

Problem I:

I have a string in the form of:

```
String = "%C3%85"
```

`String` is the representation of two bytes in UTF-8 encoding this char: "Å".
Except: "\x" is replaced with "%".

So I want to alter *String* to look like this:

```
String = "\xC3\x85"
```

Problem II:

I have a String in the form:

```
*String* = "\\x33"
```

Now I want to convert it into the UTF-8 byte representation of that which should look like:

```
String = b"\x33"
```

How do I do that?

Approaches I tried:

I tried using the replace method:

```
string.replace("%","\")  -- wont work since \ escapes "
string.replace("%","\\") -- wont work since this produces problem II
string.replace("%","\x00").replace("00","") -- wont work since "\x00" is a char by its own.

bytes(string.replace("%","\\") ) -- wont work since this basically comes down to problem II
```

One approach that works but is way more work than seems to be needed is to create a dictionary with all characters in the form of:

```
"%00" = "\x00"
...
...
```

But well....this should be automatable since its basically just replacing % with x\

I am out of luck and couldnt find any help anywhere on the internet.

lmgtfy wont help me either;)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What approaches did u try, so we don't give you the same approach.

Comment: I tried using the replace method: 
string.replace("%","\")  -- wont work since \ escapes "
string.replace("%","\\") -- wont work since this produces problem II
string.replace("%","\x00").replace("00","") -- wont work since "\x00" is a char by its own.


bytes(string.replace("%","\\") ) -- wont work since this basically comes down to problem II

One approach that works but is way more work than seems to be needed is to create a dictionary with all characters in the form of:

"%00" = "\x00"

Answer (score 1):

Both problems can probably be solved with the standard library.

Problem I looks like [URL-Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL-Encoding), ie. the kind of "garbling" you see in query strings in the browser's address bar.
In Python 3, the `urllib` module can handle this:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote('%C3%85')
'Å'
```

For Problem II, you seem to have escape sequences as they are used in Python's string literals.
As you might know, you can type `'å'` or `'\xe5'` in the source code to get exactly the same string, just as you can type `0.1`, `.1` or `1e-1` to get the same float value.
Since the Python interpreter sees the four characters `\`, `x`, `e` and `5` in your source code, it must have a way to convert this sequence into the character `å`. And (part of) this algorithm is made available to Python programmers through the "unicode_escape" codec, which you can use like "normal" codecs such as "utf-8":

```
>>> '\\x33'.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')
'3'
```

Since Python 3's `str` type has no `decode()` method, you have to encode it to bytes first.
If your input contains ASCII characters only, the above line works; also "latin-1" is possible for a mixture of Latin-1 characters and `\xNN` escapes.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, however I cant seem to find a useable explanation of the usage of the unicode_escape codec. 

From the description: 
"Encoding suitable as the contents of a Unicode literal in ASCII-encoded Python source code, except that quotes are not escaped. Decodes from Latin-1 source code. Beware that Python source code actually uses UTF-8 by default."

I wouldnt have been able to tell this codec will solve this issues. 

Can you give me a short guide to what unicode_escape is capable of, or give me some guidelines or links as to how to teach it to me myself?

Comment: @Nord.Kind You are absolutly right, I wrote my answer in a haste and didn't explain anything. I edited the answer to include a bit of background.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. However may I ask you for a little guide into the "unicode_escape" encoding?

I cant seem to find any explanation as to what expect from it in different cases.

What for example does this sentence tell me?

"Encoding suitable as the contents of a Unicode literal in ASCII-encoded Python source code, except that quotes are not escaped"

A normal String in python 3 is a unicode string afaik, so the encoding makes the decoded-bytestring useable for this(thats what I would expect of any encoding). However python source code should be utf8 encoded afaik.

Comment: So I am not sure what to make off this.

Also "except that quotes are not escaped".

How can quotes not be escaped?  I dont quite understand what they mean

Comment: It's cumbersome to explain this in a comment. Can you post a new question about it? Send me a link here once you did so, and I'll try to answer it (or somebody else who sees it before me).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have string representation of a hex encoded character byte array.  You need to convert it from a string to hex, then let Python interpret it as the UTF-8 character encoding.  Try this:

```
import re 

String = "%C3%85"
out = bytearray(int(c, 16) for c in re.findall(r'%(\w\w)', String)).decode('utf8')
out
# returns:
'Å'
```

For you second part, the binary representation of `'\x33'` is `b'3'`.  To get from the string `'\\x33'` to `b'3'`, you again need to strip out the string formatting, convert the string characters to hex, and convert to bytes.

```
String = '\\x33'
out = bytes(int(c, 16) for c in re.findall(r'\\x(\w\w)', String))
out
# returns:
b'3'
```